# Uneven Deck Boards

Tags: sanding, hand-planing

I have all my deck boards screwed down to the joists. Some ends stick up 1/8 inch or more from the others. There are many areas like this. How do I fix this? Sander or planer? It would have to be some sort of an angle from the low board graduating to the top of the high board.

[image: uneven deck boards]

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot see your picture right now, but if there are screws involved and they're not sunk, you'll destroy a plane blade if you hit one. In that case, sanding may be a safer (for the tools) option, even if the work is slower. If you're hand planing, you may be fine if you're careful to not hit any fasteners.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackExchange. Sanding over planing for this for sure, since just one screw head that isn't sunk low enough could be catastrophic. And depending on the sander this could be pretty quick work. In case it's not obvious you'd start with *really* coarse paper, probably coarser than you're thinking (well below 60). But what kind of sander were you thinking, something you already own or will you be hiring? You're not gonna do this in a reasonable time using a typical homeowner-level ROS, even with 36 grit.

Answer (score 2):

First the disclaimer, wood moves expands and contracts and twists etc.  So even getting it flat it is quite likely to become 'unflat' again after some time (at least in places).

That being said, renting a (hardwood) floor sander would make short work of this and the bonus of not needing to crawl around on your hands and knees.  You'd probably only need 36 and 60 grit to do the whole job.  I had around 400 sq. ft. of hardwood flooring and it took me just a few hours (5-6?), a deck of similar size I would expect to take less than half as long.

Comment: Yes this, with the caveat that the screw heads have to be sunk *deep* anywhere the wood is raised which isn't quite as easy as punching nails lower.

Comment: @Graphus yes, while the screws probably won't slow down the belt sander much, smoothing out the heads of your screws will cause much gnashing of teeth later.

Comment: God yes! Can you imagine trying to remove screws with their heads sanded down by about 50%?

Answer (score 2):

@bowlturner has the right answer, but here's a hack.

If it’s only the perpendicular board, just unscrew it and shim it to the level of the highest board. A few boards might be a bit low, but that’s less noticeable (imho) than a high point. If the low boards were terrible, you could shim them too.